# Ubuntu One Files

Tags: ubuntu-one

Ok so I had an "album" of photos I had forgotten was even on Ubuntu One, as I hadn't accessed my Ubuntu One account in years.
These were photos from when I was much younger from a computer that is long gone and the HDD wiped and disposed of. I wanted them gone, so I "desynced" the folder from my account.

Now the files are gone, but where? I was not given an option to delete, just desync the folder. Where did the files go? Were they deleted? Are they floating around on the "cloud" somewhere still? If so, how can I have them deleted since now I can't see the album?

Any help is great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always login to your U1 account from anywhere, even your smartphone!

So **just login**(if your brain is as clever as Einstein's to remember password after years. Most people won't. If you don't remember, reset it) and check if they are there.Then **delete them**.

BTW they shouldn't be there.they are probably deleted.

> Desync is nothing but delete.You don't need any reconfirmation.

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood. I logged into my U1 account from Google Chrome. I then selected the Album containing the photos I wanted DELETED. However, I was not presented with the option to do so, only desync the folder from my account.
I want to know, if by desyncing the folder or album so to say, were the photos physically deleted from the Cloud Server on which U1 files are located?

Comment: @Cracked_Jack yes they were deleted.But still to ensure, you may manually calculate the remaining size in your U1 account.It should be 5Gb-(size of files in U1).

Comment: @Cracked_Jack desync is nothing but deletion.Unless you are next leader of taliban, there is no reason why canonical or anyone would want to keep those photo's.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation of deletion. I simply wanted to be sure that I did not need to go through further steps to ensure my data was deleted.